# how char array will behaves ? when it is typecasted to a pointer to a structure ?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have one requirement an array arr[256] is typecasted to a pointer to structure
before sending to a function and receiving as a pointer then they were trying to access as arr[0].x, arr[1].x

struct a { x };

Can anyone explain how a regular char array is typecasted to a structure before passing to a function

Comment: I have no idea what I just read.  I want my 14 seconds back.

Comment: If you try to use an array of `char` as the storage for a structure, you have to worry about alignment requirements.  An array of `char` can be aligned on any boundary, but most structures need to be aligned on a 2-byte, 4-byte or 8-byte boundary because of the types used within the structure.  Thus, you can easily end up with problems because of misaligned addresses.  You also have to worry about strict aliassing, though as there are exemptions for `char *`, you may be OK.  in general, what you're doing isn't strictly standard compliant, though you'll usually get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are really asking, but threw together a quick program demonstrating what I *think* you are trying to do. “array .. typecasted to a pointer to structure before sending to a function” and trying to access members.

Use this as a starting point to experiment. Note that I have an integer in the structure to show you issues with endianness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct some_struct
{
   char a;
   char b;
   char c;
   char d;
   int  i;
};


void some_function(struct some_struct* p_out, struct some_struct* p_in)
{
   memcpy(p_out, p_in, sizeof(struct some_struct));

   printf("In Function:\n");
   printf("%c \n",      p_in->a);
   printf("%c \n",      p_in->b);
   printf("%c \n",      p_in->c);
   printf("%c \n",      p_in->d);
   printf("0x%X \n\n",  p_in->i);
}


int main (void)
{  
   char buffer[32] = "test1234this5678";

   struct some_struct struct1;
   struct some_struct struct2;

   some_function(&struct1, (struct some_struct*)buffer);

   int next_offset = sizeof(struct some_struct);
   some_function(&struct2, (struct some_struct*)(buffer + next_offset));

   printf("Outside Function:\n");
   printf("%c \n",      struct1.a);
   printf("%c \n",      struct1.b);
   printf("%c \n",      struct1.c);
   printf("%c \n",      struct1.d);
   printf("0x%X \n\n",  struct1.i);

   printf("%c \n",      struct2.a);
   printf("%c \n",      struct2.b);
   printf("%c \n",      struct2.c);
   printf("%c \n",      struct2.d);
   printf("0x%X \n",    struct2.i);
}
```

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Yes thats what i need you understand clearly thanks :)